# R - Removing all outliers from a data set

Tags: r

I'd like to make a function that removes all outliers from a data set. I've read a lot of Stack Overflow articles about this, so I am aware of the dangers of removing outliers. Here's what I have so far:

```
# Remove outliers from a column
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
  y
}

# Removes all outliers from a data set
remove_all_outliers <- function(df){
  # We only want the numeric columns
  a<-df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)]
  b<-df[,sapply(df, !is.numeric)]
  a<-lapply(a,function(x) remove_outliers(x))
  d<-merge(a,b)
  d
}
```

There are a few things wrong with this that I know of, but please correct me if anything could be handled better.

1. `!is.numeric()` is not a thing, How should I accomplish this?

   - I have allso tried `is.numeric==FALSE`
2. `is.numeric()` converts factors into ints. How do I prevent this?
3. Did I do `lapply` right?
4. Is there a better / easier way to perform the remove_outliers function than separating the data set, performing it, then merging it back with the non-numeric set?

Comment: Try `b<-df[,!sapply(df, is.numeric)]`

Comment: `is.numeric()` does NOT convert factors to integers. And how would you imagine a merge operation would proceed when the two dataframes had no column in common?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Factors are ints, just not atomic ints.

```
# Remove outliers from a column
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
  y
}
```

You can replace the columns by index so you don't need to create separate data sets. Just make sure you pass the same data to `lapply`, eg, you don't want to do `data[, 1:3] <- lapply(data, FUN)` which I have done many times.

```
# Removes all outliers from a data set
remove_all_outliers1 <- function(df){
  # We only want the numeric columns
  df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)] <- lapply(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)], remove_outliers)
  df
}
```

Similar to above (and slightly easier I think), you can pass the entire data set to `lapply`. Also making sure not to

```
data <- lapply(data, if (x) something else anotherthing)
```

or

```
data[] <- lapply(data, if (x) something)
```

Which are also mistakes I have made many times

```
remove_all_outliers2 <- function(df){
  df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if (is.numeric(x))
    remove_outliers(x) else x)
  df
}

## test
mt <- within(mtcars, {
  mpg <- factor(mpg)
  gear <- letters[1:2]
})
head(mt)

identical(remove_all_outliers1(mt), remove_all_outliers2(mt))
# [1] TRUE
```

Your ideas can work with a few minor adjustments. `!is.numeric` can work as either `Negate(is.numeric)` or the more verbose `function(x) !is.numeric(x)` or `!sapply(x, is.numeric)`. Generally, `function(function)` doesn't work in r out of the box.

```
# Removes all outliers from a data set
remove_all_outliers <- function(df){
  # We only want the numeric columns

  ## drop = FALSE in case only one column for either
  a<-df[,sapply(df, is.numeric), drop = FALSE]
  b<-df[,sapply(df, Negate(is.numeric)), drop = FALSE]

  ## note brackets
  a[]<-lapply(a, function(x) remove_outliers(x))

  ## stack them back together, not merge
  ## you could merge if you had a unique id, one id per row
  ## then make sure the columns are returned in the original order
  d<-cbind(a,b)
  d[, names(df)]
}

identical(remove_all_outliers2(mt), remove_all_outliers(mt))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. The one thing I'm not sure if you addressed is `is.numeric` changing factors into `int`s. Does this solution (I think the last function definition - although I'm not sure what `identical` does (proves?) here.

Comment: @TravisHeeter the `is.*` functions don't do coercion; `as.numeric` would convert factors to their integer equivalent. similarly, the other `as.*` functions do coercion. with `identical`, I was just trying to convince you that all the methods give the same results

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. Are you saying there's no way to exclude factors from this process?

Comment: @TravisHeeter not with `is.numeric`, you can use `is.factor` or one of the others depending on your needs `is.numeric(factor(1)); is.integer(factor(1)); is.factor(factor(1)); is.character(factor(1))`